# Google API V3 OAUTH2 Hang - TokenResponse-user Credentials File not created

Tags: youtube-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

**Google API V3 OAUTH2 Problem Report**

The **GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync** code below works fine on my Windows 8.1. When I install on my Windows 7 PC and run the EXE, the **AuthorizeAsync** is executed, the browser opens and I click through the **Select an account page** and the **This app would like to:** page and then see a page for a short time that says **Received verification code. Closing...** There is no **TokenResponse-user** file saved in the ..\AppData\Roaming\Google.Apis.Auth folder and my EXE hangs (waits forever). I have tried with both Chrome and Internet Explorer browsers.

Works fine on Windows 8.1 PC but hangs on Windows 7 PC. I tried two different Windows 7 PCs. The same Client ID/Secret and same Google Username/Password were used on all of the PCs.

Is there something different I should be doing in my code or is this a problem with the Google API V3 client libraries?

```
Private Async Function GetGredentials() As Task
        OAUth2Credential = Await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync( _
                New ClientSecrets With {.ClientId = Google_ClientID, .ClientSecret = Google_ClientSecret}, _
                {YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube}, "user", CancellationToken.None)
End Function
```

Versions on my PCs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Google.Apis" version="1.8.2" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Google.Apis.Auth" version="1.8.2" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Google.Apis.Core" version="1.8.2" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Google.Apis.YouTube.v3" version="1.8.1.1080" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="log4net" version="2.0.3" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.9" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Async" version="1.0.168" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.14" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.22" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.3" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Zlib.Portable" version="1.10.0" targetFramework="net40" />
</packages>
```

The Chrome History shows this but there is no file in the Google.Apis.Auth folder:

```
9:50 AM OAuth 2.0 Authentication Token Received localhost
9:50 AM Request for Permission accounts.google.com
```

Comment: Do you get exceptions?

Comment: Tim, no exceptions are thrown. My EXE waits forever after the call to GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution. Here is how I arrived at the solution.

I decided to try copying the **Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse-user** from my Windows 8.1 PC to my Windows 7 PC to see if a refresh of the token file would work because a first time creation of the token file did not work. A refresh did work. The **GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync** did a refresh of the token file and exited properly back to my EXE program.

But, another problem surfaced.

In the next step of my EXE program, while executing a **ChannelsResource.ListRequest**, I got this error message box:

> Could not load type 'System.Net.HttpStatusCode' from assembly
>   'System.Net, Version 4.0.9.9, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

A search revealed that someone else had seen the same error and was advised to install Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 update **KB2468871**. I did so and now my **ChannelsResource.ListRequest** executed properly.

I deleted the **Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse-user** token file and re-ran my EXE program executing the **GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync** to create a new token file. This time it worked properly.

My conclusion is that the same **Could not load type 'System.Net.HttpStatusCode'** exception occurred during the execution of **GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync** but it was not trapped and reported.

### **Google API V3 Documentation**

The following prerequisite requirement should be added to the Google API V3 documentation:

Install Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 update **KB2468871** (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3556)

**N.B.** Later, after experiencing yet another problem, I discovered that the Windows 7 PC did not have all of the latest updates from Windows Update. Using Windows Update to get all of the updates solved the problem documented in [System.InvalidOperationException in MSCORLIB when Google API V3 .UploadAsync is called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24688623/system-invalidoperationexception-in-mscorlib-when-google-api-v3-uploadasync-is/24703957#24703957)

### **Further Information**

I had to manually add the following files that were installed in the project's folder from NuGet into the InstallShield LE Setup Project's **Files** tab so that they would be copied to the target system. For some reason, the InstallShield LE Setup project did not automatically add these files. It added all of the others.

```
System.Net.Http.dll
System.Net.Http.WebRequest.dll
System.Runtime.dll
System.Threading.Tasks.dll
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! I added a new issue in our issue tracker - https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/detail?id=476. Feel free to add more data to it. Thanks again.