# System.InvalidOperationException in MSCORLIB when Google API V3 .UploadAsync is called

Tags: youtube-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

After resolving the problem documented in [Google API V3 OAUTH2 Hang - TokenResponse-user Credentials File not created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24642877/google-api-v3-oauth2-hang-tokenresponse-user-credentials-file-not-created/24676442#24676442), I resumed testing my EXE deployed onto a Windows 7 PC. Again, this program works fine on my Windows 8.1 development system. The deployed version on a Windows 7 PC fails as documented below.

On the Windows 7 PC, my program successfully executed *GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync, ChannelsResource.ListRequest, VideoCategoriesResource.ListRequest*, and initialization of the objects prior to starting the video file upload.  When my program executed the *videosInsertRequest.UploadAsync*, a system error message box was displayed with the following information.

```
 youtubeupload.exe has stopped working

 Windows can check online or a solution to the problem.

-> Check online for a solution and close the program
-> Close the program

View problem details


Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: youtubeupload.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 2.0.1.0
  Problem Signature 03: 53bf2a89
  Problem Signature 04: mscorlib
  Problem Signature 05: 4.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 06: 52ccf750
  Problem Signature 07: 1575
  Problem Signature 08: 47
  Problem Signature 09: System.InvalidOperationException
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

The link to check for a solution does not return any suggestions. I suspect that another Microsoft KB Update needs to be installed on the Windows 7 PC but have no idea, at this time, how to determine which one.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get my program to work so this problem is solved.

On the Windows 7 PC, I checked the Microsoft **Windows Update** page and found that it displayed:

```
You receive updates: Managed by your system administrator
```

A link on the page allowed me to check online for updates. I did that and found 152 updates including some for .NET Framework updates. It took several restarts and re-runs of Windows Update to get all of the updates installed. After they were all installed, I tried my EXE again and it worked!!!

Later, I found out that this PC was not properly registered in WSUS so was not getting updates.